# Divs are not staying in the same place and re sizing when screen shrinks

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys i am using bootstrap and media queries to make my website mobile responsive. For some reason those it keeps mucking up my desgin. I am curretnly trying to make this happen:

[image]

The big div behind is an image. Then on the left hand side we have a div with buttons, the div in the middle is anther image and then the divs on the right is some more small images. Now i have created this desgin, but everytimne u start to shrink the screem the divs on the right end up below the middle div and then the middle div ends up below the left div. Its very weird. Any help in fixing this would be great.

Fiddle example here: [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/9LFKV/139/)

I am guessing its something to do with my main Div

```
.Mainimage {

}
```

So i am using bootstrap with the cold-mid 2 etc and then using some media queries to try and make it better when it become smsall but its not working at all, any help would be great . 
Thanks

Comment: you are simply missing the row which should come just before your third div i.e. with class 'col-md-2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add following css will do the trick.

```
.Mainimage {
    display: flex;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9LFKV/141/)**